# Media Queries ignored

Tags: css, media-queries, media

I have a slight problem, my css media queries are ignored, or the main css is.

I'm trying to change the value of a size font in media queries, for desktops is 75px and for mobiles `(max-width:320px;)` is 40px or so. But it doesn't work.

My css media query code is:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  h1.site-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-weight: 800; 
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}
```

When I change the font-size value in the media queries css, it changes in the whole page. (Desktop, tablet, etc.)

What I'm doing wrong ? :(

Thank you,

Cheers

PS: the CSS Media Queries is a separate file, added in the html head, and I have this line to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

make sure your media query is placed AFTER the original declaration:

This will work:  [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvrKQ/)

```
.test{
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}

@media (max-width:500px){
.test{
    width:200px;
}
}
```

This won't work: [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvrKQ/1/)

```
@media (max-width:500px){
.test{
    width:200px;
}
}
.test{
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: At the end it worked with the twitter bootstrap media queries snippets. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your query says that the media type is screen and min-width is 320px. This is true for a desktop, so the css applies to a Desktop also. If you need it specifically for a tablet then you will have to add some property that is false for a Desktop but true for other device. `max-width` is one such property.

Do take a look at this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: That much I know, but when I use max-width is not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your media query is on the 'body' level. Otherwise your viewport's min-width won't be recognized.